# Sample Login validation Rails "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I making a simple login validation and I want to validate the name and the password.

finances_controller .rb

```
  def login
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:user])
    if @user
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    end

  end
```

login.html.erb

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
Nome: <%= f.text_field :name %>
Senha: <%= f.password_field :password %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is the error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <h1>Login</h1>
2: <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
3: Nome: <%= f.text_field :name %>
4: Senha: <%= f.password_field :password %>
5: <%= f.submit %>
```

model
user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_digest

end
```

ps: the digest is to make this secure.

Can anybody provide any inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you're searching a user by her name, but giving a hash consisted of user attributes as an argument (`params[:user]`). I think that's the reason `@user` remains `nil` and this error is shown.

could you check if changing the argument to `params[:user][:name]` gives better result?

Comment: return this error whit (params[:user][:name])

    `undefined method []' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: it seems like `params[:user]` is nil. please check params that you're sending

Comment: i send this `<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
Nome: <%= f.text_field :name %>
Senha: <%= f.password_field :password %>
<%= f.submit %><%end%>`